# Krajee file-input widget 'upload' method throws exception

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am using fileinput widget form krajee: 
http://plugins.krajee.com/file-input

What I am doing wrong using 'upload' method ?
When I upload files by pressing upload button everything works great. But when try to use upload method like this:

```
$( '#projectFiles' ).fileinput( 'upload' );
```

I get an error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'undefined' of undefined
```

in line 989.

I checked this is this line:

```
formdata.append(self.uploadFileAttr, files[i]);
```

and files are *undefined* there.

So what am I doing wrong?
My code:

[js]

```
$( "#projectFiles" ).fileinput( {
browseClass: 'btn btn-default',
showPreview: true,
showUpload: true,
multiple: "multiple",
uploadAsync: true,
uploadUrl: "/home/UploadFiles"
} );

function submitForm( e ) {
$( '#projectFiles' ).fileinput( 'upload' );
// atach to event 'filebatchuploadsuccess' then submit rest of form
}
```

[ASP MVC view]

```
@using( Html.BeginForm( "RequestPost", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "frmRequest", @class = "", enctype = "multipart/form-data" } ) )
{
<div id="projectFilesDiv" class="row">
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
<div class="form-group">
<input id="projectFiles" name="projectFiles" type="file"/>
</div>
</div>
</div>

@* THE REST OF THE FORM *@


<button type="button" onclick="submitForm()">SUBMIT</button>
}
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is that I have older version of control (4.1.6) and documentation I have red is newer (4.1.7). 
In 4.1.6 ***upload*** method must have parameters, in 4.1.7 not
In 4.1.6 the solution might be use ***uploadBatch*** which has no parameters (what I finally did)

Answer (score 1):

If you are just looking for a file upload plugin, I recommend Ravishanker Kusuma's `Hayageek jQuery File Upload plugin`:

http://hayageek.com/docs/jquery-upload-file.php

He breaks down the process into three simple steps, that basically look like this:

```
<head>
    <link href="http://hayageek.github.io/jQuery-Upload-File/uploadfile.min.css" rel="stylesheet">  // (1)
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://hayageek.github.io/jQuery-Upload-File/jquery.uploadfile.min.js"></script>   // (1)
</head>
<body>
    <div id="fileuploader">Upload</div>  // (2)
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#fileuploader").uploadFile({  // (3)
                url:"my_php_processor.php",
                fileName:"myfile"
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

The final step is to have the PHP file specified in the jQuery code (in this case `my_php_processor.php`) to receive and process the file:

**my_php_processor.php:**

```
<?php
    $output_dir = "uploads/";
    $theFile = $_FILES["myfile"]["name"];
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["myfile"]["tmp_name"],$output_dir.$fileName);
```

*Note the relationship between `myfile` in the PHP (`$_FILES["myfile"]`), and the filename specified in the jQuery code block.*

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue, but I couldn't find a good solution, so I came up with a workaround.

I'm using the 'filebatchuploadcomplete' event, so I know when all the files in the batch are uploaded succesfully (even if there's only one file in the batch to be uploaded). 
When this event is triggered, I call 3 methods of the fileinput inside the closure function to clear, reset and re-enable the fileinput area (dropzone too, if you're using one).

THIS METHOD WORKS REGARDLESS IF THE ABOVE MENTIONED ERROR IS THROWN OR NOT BY THE PLUGIN.

Here's my sample:

```
$('#myFileuploadArea').fileinput({

    //set the upload options here
    ...
    ...
    ...

}).on("filebatchselected", function(event) {

    // trigger upload method immediately after files are selected
    $('#myFileuploadArea').fileinput("upload");

}).on('filebatchuploadcomplete', function(event) {

    // this part is triggered when all files are succefully 
    // uploaded from the batch, even if there was only one file selected
    console.log('ALL FILES IN BATCH UPLOADED SUCCESSFULLY');
    $('#myFileuploadArea').fileinput('refresh');
    $('#myFileuploadArea').fileinput('reset');
    $('#myFileuploadArea').fileinput('enable');

});
```