# Trouble getting data on server from FormData

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, file-upload

I am having trouble uploading a picture file via AJAX.

Web:

```
<div>
    <form id="birdi_image_form">
        <input type="file" name="birdi_image" id="birdi_image" ></input>
    </form>

    <input type="text" name="species"></input>
    <textarea name="comments"></textarea>
</div>
<div id="debug"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">

jQuery(function($){
    $('#birdi_image').change(function(){
        var ima = new FormData($('#birdi_image_form')[0]);

        $.ajax({
            url:"/bird/bird_scripts/fu.php",
            type:"post",
            data: ima,
            processData: false,
            dataType:"text",
            success:function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                $('#debug').text(data);
            }
        });
    });
});

</script>
```

/bird/bird_scripts/fu.php:

```
<?php

$imagedir = '/images';
$tmpfname = tempnam($imagedir, "b_");

echo var_dump($_POST);

if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['birdi_image']['tmp_name'], $tmpfname)) {
  echo "File is valid, and was successfully uploaded.\n";
} else {
   echo "Upload failed";
}

?>
```

From looking around online I was expecting to find contents in my `$_FILES` variable, but this is empty.  Dumping out the `$_POST` var to the screen like in the example gives me the following.  `$_POST['birdi_image']` gives me `NULL`.

> array(68) { ["------WebKitFormBoundaryYCAoI8shwgBavjJP 
>   Content-Disposition:_form-data;_name"]=> string(339) ""birdi_image";
>   filename="test.jpg"  Content-Type: image/jpeg    ����JFIFdd�� 
>   ExifMM*bj(1r2��i��B@'B@'Adobe Photoshop
>   CS2 Windows2008:06:24 11:11:48��b�g"
>   ["?o��(�ci�\�R��Μꟑ���]T��z���"]=> string(82) "���
>   f�zߠ����i`���/��v��E~��[,�Y
>   �s�������1l�G����-���߿�enu'=�v�z���=?Ҳ���"
>   ["�{��<o��ӗ�M��ysnʨo87~;l���۔�"]=> string(172) "�<��t�2~���O�S
>   �����t���㵺C�}E������}��I�d]c���y}#�����C,�Z��־��V��ynʿ��?�g�*����o��ٌ�.}�y����}��z����w^�]�m�u������z>�37�_C긵��K�Y-{��뺷��M���ul��Y�"
>   ["c�yhHp����"]=> string(152)
>   "��[-���1�]��|�����۽Q�\�e���o�~��g������u�.���A��t�]�3�W�ד��b���}>�����%��K���Ѳ�3���zX��qZ��}u��sc�
>   ���N� ^-w�7���\r� ����c��=?՗δX�j" ["C�uw���-��"]=> string(57)
>   "���m��w��������ѩ���������k��r����m�t�62rIk���m�ߗV��}" ["�"]=>
>   string(384)
>   "!�<��B���6*�c��劷Q���uF*��U��������ď,�`y{R���������E%���Q����5.��IE��*�N�����Ο�̿4~R��...............Upload failed.

I have uploaded files before by using a complete form submit.  This is the first time I am trying to do it with AJAX.  It looks like the data is getting to the server, but I can't seem to make any sense of it from the server side.  As you can see in the code I expected `$_FILES['birdi_image']` to exist but it doesn't.  Am I doing something completely wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to set the content type to false, otherwise jQuery will set one(the wrong one) for you

```
    $.ajax({
        url:"/bird/bird_scripts/fu.php",
        type:"post",
        data: ima,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        dataType:"text",
        success:function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            $('#debug').text(data);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

I struggled with this also - it's just not as easy as it should be. I finally found a guy who did it right, and studied his code.

[Ravi Kusuma's jQuery File Upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28608548/krajee-file-input-widget-upload-method-throws-exception/28609251#28609251)

In the end, because Kusuma wrote a plugin, I just used his code/plugin. Why re-invent the wheel? He's got everything solved, right down to sending extra data along with the uploaded file.